# Xcode automatically deletes Tools/mogenerator on build

Tags: ios, xcode, mogenerator

Yesterday, without provocation, Xcode started automatically deleting the `Tools/mogenerator` file in my project every time I build. When I discard the resultant git deletion (put the file back) and rebuild, Xcode promptly deletes the file again. This file is needed for a run script in my project so deleting it obviously breaks my builds, but there appears to be no way to convince Xcode to just leave it where it belongs.

I have:

- Cleaned and rebuilt
- Run `git clean -fdx`
- Deleted `Xcode/DerievedData`
- Restarted my machine
- Nuked and recloned the repo
- Cloned the repo into a different folder
- Updated Xcode
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode

I've done most of those multiple times.

I am the only one on my team who is having this issue, and a clean clone of the repo gives me the exact same problem, so I'm confident it doesn't have anything to do with my code. It has to be something in my environment. But I can't recall doing anything that would affect my environment like this. Yesterday I built without issue, and 5 minutes later I built again and this happened. I didn't change anything.

I'm at a complete loss as are all the other engineers on my team. None of us have seen anything like this before, and nothing we have tried has worked. Does this sound familiar to anyone? Is there another step I can take to clean my environment?

## Update

It appears this run script in the Mogenerator target is what's causing the trouble. Initially I assumed it worked because it was the only thing that references `Tools/mogenerator`, but it turns out when I remove it the file isn't deleted at all and everything works normally. Everyone else on my team has the exact same script, so I have no idea why it's causing problems for only me.

`Tools/mogenerator -m #/#.xcdatamodeld --machine-dir #/Model/Generated --human-dir #/Model --swift --template-var arc=true --template-var scalarsWhenNonOptional=true`

Comment: try installing an environment in a virtual machine.

Comment: Try looking at the build log (View menu -> Navigators -> Reports, or cmd-9) to see if you can find a step where it gets deleted.

Comment: @TomHarrington I don't see anything that looks suspicious. Is there something particular you'd recommend I look for?

Comment: Not exactly, but removing files like this is not something Xcode normally does. However it does document its steps in the build log, so it seems like a good place to look for information. I'd try exporting the build log as a text file (the "Export..." button at the top) so you can see every command executed. Scan the file for any mention of mogenerator.